# Nested data in postgres

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I have a CSV with columns of various data types, including what i would interpret as nested data.

The nested data comes in many forms.

**For example**:
[13,11,23,18,18,21,23,16,8,20,22,18,20,17,13,10,8,19,16,21,15,12,8,12,14,26,26,20,12]

**Another example in a different form**:
{"<5":1,"5-20":36,"21-60":149,"61-240":215,">240":86}

I'm currently storing these as strings but i was hoping there was a more flexible data type i could store them as to allow more powerful selection that could allow me to query the nested data.  I'm quite new to postgres but from the research ive done it looks like i have two options

For the first example I could use arrays (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-array/) and for the second example json (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/).

So my questions are:

1. Am I using the right data types or will I run into issues down the line from using these?
2. Whats the right way to import this?

UPDATE:
When importing this from CSV after trying to use array and json I now get an error 'Malformed array literal'.  I made the quote and escape character " after getting an 'unterminated CSV quoted field error' which now leaves me with this new error.

Found the issue on the above. The CSV I was importing from used brackets ([ and ]) to hold the arrays which was causing the issue.  I changed to curly braces ({ and }) and this fixed the error.

This (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170099/copy-import-data-into-postgresql-array-column) got me in the right direction.

Comment: Images are a bad idea here for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) - can you post these as text? Are there the same number of data points in the different `visits_by_day` lines? To what do these lines correspond? RDBMS do best with `relations` - i.e. tables - it's the `R` in `RDBMS` - if you can possibly put your data into tables, then this is the **best** way to go!  At least you're using PostgreSQL, so you have a fighting chance of being able to come up with a reasonably performant solution :-).  p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: p.p.s. PostgreSQL has [`interval`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-interval/) types which could be useful for your `bucketed_dwell_times` data?

Comment: thx for feedback.  updated to text.  I do currently have them in tables, just with text dtypes and i wanted to enable more powerful selecting on the columns that have more complex data structures (i.e. array/json) than just text/numbers.  Interval does seem interesting but since the original value is in json i thought i would need to import it as a json dtype first and then i could convert the values within to intervals.  Thx again.